# How to split a string by a specific char if the line ONLY contains that specific delimiter

Tags: c#, text, split

I real all lines from a text file to a var like this:

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
```

I now need to split that text by this delimiter '/'.
But that text can contain '/' anywhere since is filled with SQL statements, so I need to split only when the '/' it's "alone" in that line so I don't split accidentally a command.

I think I should use a regex? I'm not handy with them?
Is there any way to condition the `text.Split()` for what I need?

This is the file:

```
ALTER TABLE ORC
    ADD MercadoInt  VARCHAR2(1)
    ADD Coef_KrMo   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrMt   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrEq   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrSb   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrGb   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_MDEmp  NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_MDLoc  NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Abrv_MDLoc  VARCHAR2(10)
    ADD Dsc_MDLoc   VARCHAR2(50)
    ADD Arred_MDLoc VARCHAR2(1)
    ADD Arred_NDecs NUMBER(1)
/
UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt='N', Coef_KrMo=1, Coef_KrMt=1, Coef_KrEq=1, Coef_KrSb=1, Coef_KrGb=1, Coef_MDEmp=1, Coef_MDLoc=1, Abrv_MDLoc='', Dsc_MDLoc='', Arred_MDLoc='N', Arred_NDecs=0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/
```

The output should be a list containing only the commands like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ORC
        ADD MercadoInt  VARCHAR2(1)
        ADD Coef_KrMo   NUMBER(20,10)
        ADD Coef_KrMt   NUMBER(20,10)
        ADD Coef_KrEq   NUMBER(20,10)
        ADD Coef_KrSb   NUMBER(20,10)
        ADD Coef_KrGb   NUMBER(20,10)
        ADD Coef_MDEmp  NUMBER(20,10)
        ADD Coef_MDLoc  NUMBER(20,10)
        ADD Abrv_MDLoc  VARCHAR2(10)
        ADD Dsc_MDLoc   VARCHAR2(50)
        ADD Arred_MDLoc VARCHAR2(1)
        ADD Arred_NDecs NUMBER(1)

UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt='N', Coef_KrMo=1, Coef_KrMt=1, Coef_KrEq=1, Coef_KrSb=1, Coef_KrGb=1, Coef_MDEmp=1, Coef_MDLoc=1, Abrv_MDLoc='', Dsc_MDLoc='', Arred_MDLoc='N', Arred_NDecs=0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
```

Note:
When I say split when the line only contains '/' it's because if the statement contains a '/' it will also divide it, which can't happen, so I can only split it when the line only contains '/'

Comment: Show some of those lines and the desired result for atleast one of those

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean with _split only when the '/' it's "alone_ You have an array of lines in memory. If a line contains only the delimiter what do you want to split?

Comment: Have a look at `Regex.Split()` where you can define a pattern for *alone* /

Comment: What sql command contains `/`?

Comment: @Steve see the updated ansewer with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `File.ReadAllText(pathToFile)` instead you can then do:

```
var result = text.Split(new[]{"\n/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This should result in a list with the two commands from your file.

Comment: why will be the difference between RealAllText and ReallAllLines?
It will give me the same output right?

Comment: No, `ReallAllLines` will give you a string array while `RealAllText` will give you the complete file as one string.

Comment: but If I do string text = File.ReadAllLines() it only returns a string.

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an array of strings not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution using regex, but following should also work.

```
foreach (String line in text){
    if (line.Count(f => f == '/') == 1){
        String[] myArray = line.Split('/')
    }
}
```